# Is there any way to share a variable between a library and a main script in python?

Tags: python, libraries

I have a main script **script.py**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
textDisplay = Entry(frame)
textDisplay.pack()
btn1=Button(root,text='add here ',command=function)
btn1.pack()
def function ():
    textDisplay.insert(0,'Some String')
    return

root.mainloop()
```

i want to create a library that contain my functions (function()), so i create **MyLib.py**

```
from script.py import textDisplay
def function ():
    textDisplay.insert(0,'Some String')
    return
```

and i add this line to **script.py**

```
from MyLib.py import *
```

so **script.py** will be:

```
from tkinter import *
from MyLib.py import *
root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
textDisplay = Entry(frame)
textDisplay.pack()
btn1=Button(root,text='add here ',command=function)
btn1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

when i run it show me an error, whats the problem?!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Hp\OneDrive\Bureau\emojiDesktopKeyboard\script.py", line 
5, in <module>
from emojiLib import *
File "c:\Users\Hp\OneDrive\Bureau\emojiDesktopKeyboard\emojiLib.py", 
line 1, in <module>
from script import textDisplay
File "c:\Users\Hp\OneDrive\Bureau\emojiDesktopKeyboard\script.py", line 
32, in <module>
btn1=Button(root,text='\U0001F600 ',command=enter1F600 ,width=5,font= 
("Arial", 15), cursor="hand2" , bg="#a9dce3")
NameError: name 'enter1F600' is not defined
```

Comment: `script` loads `mylib` which loads `script`, and so on, you may get an import error. Also, you should not use the `.py` extension when you import from other modules.

Comment: @SpaceBurger is there any solution?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille i have this scenario with a very complicated code

Comment: Now that you gave the error message, it looks like your function `enter1F600` is not defined in the current scope of you `script` module. Does it import it from somewhere else ? It doesn't seem like it's `textDisplay` in itself that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that can be used is :

**script.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from mylib import myfunc

class Display:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.frame = Frame(root)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.textDisplay = Entry(self.frame)
        self.textDisplay.pack()
        self.btn1=Button(self.root,text='add here ',command=lambda: myfunc(self.textDisplay))
        self.btn1.pack()

    def show(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    display = Display()
    display.show()
```

**mylib.py**

```py
def function(textDisplay):
    textDisplay.insert(0,'Some String')
```

Please notice the following points:

- renamed the library files to fit the usual python standard, and fixed import names
- removed cyclical import, now we have only one import of `mylib` in `script.py`
- `function()` has been modified to take an argument into account, that way you can send data from your main script to your module without importing. Then the function is called using a lambda so that it keeps the same signature.
- created a class `Display` to try and make it more readable, but it's not striclty necessary I guess
- lastly, another way to make all of this work would be to move the implementation of `function()` to the main script. But I assume you wish to keep it separated.

Comment: the program run normaly, but when i click on the button it return this error:NameError: name 'textDisplay' is not defined

Comment: do i have to use OOP?

Comment: No need for OOP, it's just for readability. You just need the content of `__init__()` and `show()`. What's important is the format of the import statements, the definition of function and its usage as a lambda.

Comment: from which file is the error raised ? in `script.py`, it should be called `self.textDisplay` if you use OOP as above and in `mylib` you should make sure your argument name is the same as the name used inside the function

Comment: thanks, it works when i use lambda function

Answer (score 0):

I try what @SpaceBurger propose, and it works:

**script.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from MyLib.py import *
root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
textDisplay = Entry(frame)
textDisplay.pack()
btn1=Button(root,text='add here ',command= lambda: myFunction(textDisplay))
btn1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**MyLib.py**

```
def myFunction(textDisplay):
    textDisplay.insert(0,'Some String')
```